# What is the best practice for multi-tenancy with AWS document DB and AWS managed workflows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, mwaa

What is the best practice for multi-tenancy with AWS document DB and AWS managed workflows?

1. Different VPCs with vpc peering:

> Is it better to create one cluster for several tenants and separate
> tenants with Role-Based Access Control? So the document DB cluster
> will be created in vpc A and managed workflows will be created in
> different vpc B, then the communication will be by vpc peering?

> If so
> can I create multi-managed workflows environments in the same vpc or
> each managed workflows environment should has herself vpc? (for
> multi-tenancy)

2. Same VPC:

> Or is it better to create AWS DocumentDB cluster and  AWS managed
> workflows per tenant on the same vpc?